# 2x ModuleNotFoundError Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

While attempting to run jupyter notebook in python3.6.3 on my gnome terminal I get the following output, running on UBUNTU:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/willem/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
     import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
     from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
     from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/willem/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
     from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/willem/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 81, in <module>
     from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/willem/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
     from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

However, the module sqlite3 is present in my python3.6.3 directory. Which makes the problem rather vague.

Any suggestions for this problem to be fixed will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which OS you are using. Some OS like UBUNTU needs underlying sqlite libraries.

Comment: If on UBUNTU try `sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`