# Running Jupyter Notebook from cmd raises ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pysqlite2

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**The problem:**

After reinstalling [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows) I can no longer navigate to a folder using the command window where I've got some `.pynb` files, type `jupyter notebook` and get things up and running. I'm getting these errors:

> C:\scripts\notebooks>jupyter notebook Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\MYUSERID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       import sqlite3   File "C:\Users\MYUSERID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *   File "C:\Users\MYUSERID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from _sqlite3 import * ImportError: DLL load failed: Procedyre not found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\MYUSERID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from notebook.notebookapp import main   File "C:\Users\MYUSERID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py",
>   line 86, in 
>       from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager   File
>   "C:\Users\MYUSERID\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

---

**What I've tried:**

---

I've checked the fresh Anaconda folders, and everything seems to be where it should wrt `sqlite`, `sqlite3` and `pysqlite2`.

Since last time I downloaded Anaconda, it seems they've changed the default install folders, so I was sure everything would be OK after editing my user and system environment variables according to the post [Jupyter notebook will not open from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318033/jupyter-notebook-will-not-open-from-command-prompt) just in case checking the `Add to Path` option upon reinstalling Anaconda was not enough. But I'm still getting the same error messages.

When I launch Jupyter from the Anaconda Navigator, everything runs fine.

A similar question has been asked, but not answered, for Ubuntu here: [2x ModuleNotFoundError Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771364/2x-modulenotfounderror-jupyter-notebook)

---

**Edit:**

---

When I use and Anaconda Prompt, jupyter also starts running just fine when entering `jupyter notebook`. So why bother with the command window? The anaconda prompt command does not open ipynb files automatically in the deafault web browser. My earlier setup with the windows command window (and a batch file) did that and I think it was very useful.

---

**System details:**

```
Windows 7, 64 bit
Anaconda 2018.12
Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4
Python 3.7.1
IPython 7.2.0
```

Comment: All these answers are for Windows & Anaconda. If anyone has a solution for Ubuntu and venv/pip, I'd love a reply to this comment.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was stuck on the same issue for like a day. finally found the solution its working now.

The issue seems to arise from the missing of **sqlite3.dll** in path ".\Anaconda\Dlls\". I solved it by simply copying that .dll file from **\Anaconda3\Library\bin** and put it under the path mentioned above. This was life saviour.

Thanks,
Darsan

Comment: Sounds great! Can't wait to check it out!

Comment: For my case: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs`

Answer (score 5):

1. from this link to download pysqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. zip the file to the dir:(anaconda3\DLLs)

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

This appears to be a version issue as of `29.01.2019` only related to:

[Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/):

```
Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) 
IPython 7.2.0
```

Check the list in the details below to see versions that will not raise the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pysqlite2` when launching Jupyter from batch, or even trying to install nbExtensions.

For version Anaconda3-2018.12, Jupyter *can* be launched from batch using the setup from GokulDAS027 [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542444/using-a-bat-to-change-directories-and-run-jupyter), but it will not open automatically in your default web browser. You can also launch Jupyter from the Anaconda Navigator without problems.

**The details:**

---

**Solution 1**: Run more detailed batch

---

It turns out that the suggestion from GokulDAS027 to the question [Using a .bat to change directories and run Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542444/using-a-bat-to-change-directories-and-run-jupyter) for some reason will open Jupyter without raising the sqlite error messages:

`C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3 C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "**file location**"`

***On my system, Jupyter will not automatically open the default web-browser though.***
Also, if you'd like to install Notebook Extensions, you'll get a related error message. Since I did not find this very satisfactory, I started some more digging on whether or not this is a problem for later versions of Anaconda as well:

---

**Solution 2:** Install older versions of Anaconda

---

I noticed some comments on github that [pysqlite2 is not used in Python 3](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4181). I was pretty certain that I did not have the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pysqlite2` about a year ago when I was already using Python 3, so I tested a few older Anaconda installations to check whether or not the same error would be raised.

It appears that the pysqlite2 error will ***only*** be raised for the very latest version (per 29.01.2019):

[Anaconda3-2018.12](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe)

```
Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) 
IPython 7.2.0
```

**With the system setups described below (still on Windows 7, 64 bit) everything runs fine, meaning:**

1. Jupyter can be started from a command prompt (not only Anaconda prompt) by navigating to a folder and typing `jupyter notebook`, *and* it's launched automatically in the default web browser.
2. nbExtensions can be installed using `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

**Tested versions from** [Anaconda Archive](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/)

**Anaconda3-5.3.1**

```
Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

**Anaconda3-4.4.0**

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)|
IPython 5.3.0
```

**Anaconda2-4.3.1-Windows-x86_64**

```
Jupyter Notebook 4.3.1
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| 
IPython 5.1.0
```

Comment: i am getting this issue too. am going to uninstall "Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows" and try "Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86.exe" from the archive. Will report back here is resolves my issue.

Comment: Do that! I'd really like to know if I'm not the only one with this issue.

Comment: that did not seem to work for me - still getting same error. https://gist.github.com/andrewm4894/957cdb9561e1529f942373865f6a7fc0 . i have it working in docker so just going to go with that instead at this stage.

Comment: I'm getting this error on Ubuntu, fwiw.  First wanted to install Jupyter into a Poetry created Virtualenv, then I gave up and tried to install via Miniconda3.  I'm not too keen on downgrading Miniconda to get this to work, seems like an issue should be logged to have this fixed.

Answer (score 2):

if you have oracle client installed for cx_Oracle package please check if you have **/usr/lib** in the **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**. Try removing /usr/bin from the path and see if it works.

I had the same problem and this worked for me. I have tried it on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for users who might have compiled Python from source and also for the users who dont have admin rights (as a result I cant use `Homebrew`). I faced the same error but my python environment is customised and I am not using anaconda or pyenv. A side note, my OS is `macOS mojave 10.14.6`.

I recompiled and reconfigured `sqlite` manually from source package. Steps:

1. Download `sqlite` [tarfile](https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/sqlite.tar.gz) from this [page](https://sqlite.org/src/dir?ci=tip).
2. Navigate to the `/path/to/python_dir/Python-3.x.x/Modules` where your `Python` version is installed. (Because I am not the admin I installed it here : `/Users/myusername/python3`. ) : `/Users/myusername/python3/Python-3.6.8/Modules/`
3. Extract `sqlite` under `/Modules/`: `tar zxf /Users/myusername/Downloads/sqlite.tar.gz`
4. `cd sqlite`
5. configure `sqlite` locally : `./configure --prefix='/Users/myusername/python3'`
   side note: without the `prefix` option `make install` will install files in default location. [check this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424786/permission-denied-while-running-make-install). So use the `prefix` option if your python is not at default location.
6. `make && make install`
7. go back to python folder and reconfigure python binaries, and point to `sqlite` :
   `cd ../../` and then:
   `./configure --prefix='/Users/myusername/python3' --with-sqlite='/Users/myusername/python3'`.
8. `make && make install`

Side note : It turns out that if you configured Python manually and you can't install some library using `pip` probably you have to configure and recompile that package from source. Download the `tar` file of your package and repeat the above steps for your package. I also had problems with `zlib` and `openssl` and i did the same as above.
Some other threads you might find useful : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3) , maybe [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 10:

Replace the file “C:\Windows\System32\sqlite3.dll” with “C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin\sqlite3.dll”