# Jupyterlab will not launch in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm firing up multiple notebooks in JuputerLab simply by navigating to the folder containing those notbooks, and typing `jupyter lab`. This opens JupyuterLab in chrome directly, whics is really neat. With some very few [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346965/running-jupyter-notebook-from-cmd-raises-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py), this has been running fine until now. For some reason, now I have to copy and paste the following to get started:

> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the firsttime, to login with a token:
>
> http://localhost:8888/?token=1a11606cd5bba635155??????1a59f24886c302b7203

Everything works fine when I do as asked, but does anyone know how I can fire up JupyterLab directly without the copy&paste?

**System info:**

```
OS:    Windows 7
Default browser: Chrome
Jupyterlab: 0.34.9
```

Answer (score 1):

On a mac, if you hold down `⌘` and hover over the link - then it will become clickable ✨

Thereby eliminating the need to both copy and paste.

Comment: but yeah i would like a way to pipe in the token too. it would be a nice alias