# Not able to launch jupyter notebook from Anaconda prompt

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When I tried running jupyter notebook from Anaconda prompt, I am getting the below error message

```
jupyter-notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\APPS\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\APPS\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\APPS\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "C:\APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Although "sqlite3" package already exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Jupyter Notebook from cmd raises ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pysqlite2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346965/running-jupyter-notebook-from-cmd-raises-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py)

Comment: I just have one version one Anaconda.