# Why an error comes up when launching Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've recently installed Anaconda so I can use `Jupyter notebook`, but when I try to launch a notebook, the following error is thrown:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 9, in 

import sqlite3
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 83, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\Arian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 12, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Comment: refere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346965/running-jupyter-notebook-from-cmd-raises-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Jupyter Notebook from cmd raises ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pysqlite2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346965/running-jupyter-notebook-from-cmd-raises-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py)