# Jupyter Notebook Installation Failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, failed-installation

I just downloaded Jupyter Notebook 3.7.4 and tried to run it. But after some seconds, the console closes itself and the notebook won't start. [image]

Edit: redownloaded Jupyter Notebook and installed it on C:, now this error pops up:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346965/running-jupyter-notebook-from-cmd-raises-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py

Comment: I actually fixed it with NguyenDongAnh's solution, posted here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4332